# Number of functions from A to B, where C $\subseteq$ B

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Be A, B, C finite sets with C $\subseteq$ B, |A| = m, |B| = n, |C| = r; where m, n$\geq$ r. Find the number of functions f from A to B with the property C $\subseteq$ f(A).

Hello! I found the following result for this problem: number of functions is $n^m - (n - r)^m$. Could someone tell me please if this is the right answer? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(n-r)^m$ is the number of functions from $A$ to $B\setminus C$, so $n^m-(n-r)^m$ is the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ such that $f[A]\nsubseteq B\setminus C$, i.e., the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ such that $f[A]\cap C\ne\varnothing$. This isn’t what you want: you want $f[A]$ to include **every** element of $C$, not just at least one element of $C$.

You can solve this problem with an [inclusion-exclusion argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). For that we want to count the ‘bad’ functions from $A$ to $B$, the ones whose ranges don’t include all of $C$. For each $c\in C$ let $F_c$ be the set of $f:A\to B$ such that $c\notin f[A]$; $\bigcup_{c\in C}F_c$ is the set of ‘bad’ functions, so we want $\left|\bigcup_{c\in C}F_c\right|$.

For any non-empty $I\subseteq C$ there are $(n-|I|)^m$ functions from $A$ to $B\setminus I$, so the inclusion-exclusion principle says that

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{c\in C}F_c\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq C}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{c\in I}F_c\right|\\
&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq C}(-1)^{|I|+1}(n-|I|)^m\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^{k+1}\binom{r}k(n-k)^m\,,
\end{align*}$$

and subtracting this from $n^m$, the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$, will give us the desired result:

$$\begin{align*}
n^m-\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^{k+1}\binom{r}k(n-k)^m&=n^m+\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}k(n-k)^m\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom{r}k(n-k)^m\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you! I will look more in depth!

Comment: @HenryBena: You’re welcome!